# Does this regex match what I'm wanting to match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match `/events/:eventId` or `/events/:eventId/` with regex. `:eventId` can be any alphanumeric string.

This is what I have at the moment

```
str.match(/events\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/?/)
```

How can I make sure it doesn't match something like:

```
/events/das873jh/image
```

**Update**

For some reason, this code matches but puts random characters like a `,` at the end of the string when there's a match. Why?!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "/events/ji893u"; 
  var res = str.match(/^\/events\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\/)?$/);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anchors, `^` and `$`. Use  `/^events\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/?$/`

Comment: https://regex101.com/  Tons of regex testing sites out there.  Or, you know, *try it* and see

Comment: `/^\/events\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\/)?$/` would most likely do it

Comment: @Taplar Thanks but it doesn't seem to like the `^$` when I try it with javascript's match()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umy8wtx9/  you may want to use test, if you are expecting a boolean that is.

Comment: @Taplar test didn't seem to work, try my code snippet, there's something weird where it adds a `,` at the end of my matched string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match  `match()` returns an array of the substrings that match your regex.  And you are adding that array to your html.  Most likely the comma is coming from the to string of the array.  Rather than adding it to the html, console log it

Comment: Does the pattern have to be the entire line?  If not you don't need the anchor or end on line.  The patterns I see above wont match the colons either.  Try `\/events\/\:[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}\/?`

Comment: @stever `:eventId` is a place holder for a variable, unless I'm reading it wrong, so it will not contain a `:`.  Also your regex would require the string to end with a `/`, which the OP says is optional.

Comment: It matches both. The "?" makes the last `/` optional. I thought it was a route rather than a placeholder.  I'm using Sublime3 to test.  I love these exercises.  Not saying I'm good at them, just that they're fun!

Comment: Ah, I confused the last `/` as the regex closure.  herp derp

Comment: My bad.  It IS a js question.